# How to calculate date based on yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, navicat

I am looking for a simple query to calculate someones age based on yyyymmdd. I don't need to keep the records updated throughout time, I just need the age as of today.

Example - 19731026 is the birthdate for one record. I want to create a new column named age and calculate that birthdate to their current age which would be 48 years old.

Comment: Depends on your DBMS. Here's one that works in postgres: extract(year from age(now(), birth_date)). There should be dozens of search results if you search for calculate age in your dbms.

Answer (score 1):

If your database is Oracle you can use:

```
select floor(months_between(sysdate, to_date('19731026','YYYYMMDD'))/12) as age
  from dual;

       AGE
----------
        48
```